# Count the number of days in each month of a date range

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I have a data frame that includes start and end dates, like so

```
id <- c(1, 1, 2)
start <- c("2014-01-05", "2014-02-04", "2014-02-06")
end <- c("2014-02-03", "2014-04-29", "2014-03-07")
df <- data.frame(id, start, end)

 id        start          end
  1    2014-01-05   2014-02-03
  1    2014-02-04   2014-04-29
  2    2014-02-06   2014-03-07
```

I'm trying to determine how to calculate the number of dates that occur in each month between the start and the end dates. Such as the following:

```
id    month_yyyy_mm count
 1          2014-01    27
 1          2014-02     3
 1          2014-02    25
 1          2014-03    31
 1          2014-04    29
 2          2014-02    23
 2          2014-03     7
```

I'm able to convert the character strings to a date and then calculate the total difference between the start and end using `difftime`, but I'm lost as how to calculate this on a monthly basis. Is there perhaps anything in the `lubridate` package that could help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the functions `f1, f2, f3` below

```
f1 <- function(d_first,d_last){
        d_first <- as.Date(d_first)
        d_last <- as.Date(d_last)

        D <- seq(d_first, d_last, 1) # generate all days in [d_first,d_last]
        M <- unique(format(D, "%m")) # all months in [d_first,d_lst]

        f2 <- function(x) length(which(format(D, "%m") == x)) # returns number of days in month x
        res <- vapply(M,f2,numeric(1))
        return(cbind(unique(format(D, "%Y-%m")),res))
      }
f3 <- function(k) f1(df$start[k],df$end[k])

output <- sapply(1:nrow(df), f3)
```

which yields

```
> output 
[[1]]
             res 
01 "2014-01" "27"
02 "2014-02" "3" 

[[2]]
             res 
02 "2014-02" "25"
03 "2014-03" "31"
04 "2014-04" "29"

[[3]]
             res 
02 "2014-02" "23"
03 "2014-03" "7"
```

From here on now, the rest is a matter of formatting. Indeed, a simple `do.call(rbind, output)` will do the trick

```
> do.call(rbind, output)
             res 
01 "2014-01" "27"
02 "2014-02" "3" 
02 "2014-02" "25"
03 "2014-03" "31"
04 "2014-04" "29"
02 "2014-02" "23"
03 "2014-03" "7"
```

Of the top of my head, to have the IDs you could set `f4 <- function(k) cbind(df$id[k], f3(k))` and thus

```
> do.call(rbind, sapply(1:nrow(df), f4))
                 res 
01 "1" "2014-01" "27"
02 "1" "2014-02" "3" 
02 "1" "2014-02" "25"
03 "1" "2014-03" "31"
04 "1" "2014-04" "29"
02 "2" "2014-02" "23"
03 "2" "2014-03" "7"
```

But there probably are cleverer solutions.

Comment: That looks really great; do you have any recommendations on how I can keep the id column from the original dataframe included in the rows of the dataframe produced by those three functions?

Comment: Set `f4 <- function(k) cbind(df$id[k], f3(k))` - see the edit.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different approach which uses the `foverlaps()` function from the `data.table` package.

`foverlaps()` finds overlaps between a created sequence of first and last days of months and the given periods.

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

# coerce dates from character to IDate
cols <- c("start", "end")
DT <- as.data.table(df)[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, as.IDate), .SDcols = cols]

# create sequence of months which cover all periods
mon_seq <- DT[, as.IDate(seq(floor_date(min(start), unit = "months"), 
                             ceiling_date(max(end), unit = "months"),
                             by = "month"))]
# create helper data.table with first and last day of months
mDT <- data.table(start = head(mon_seq, -1L), end = tail(mon_seq, -1L) - 1L)
setkeyv(DT, cols)
# find overlapping pieces for each month
foverlaps(mDT, DT, nomatch = 0L)[
  # compute count of days in each month
  , {tmp <- pmax(start, i.start)
  .(id = id, month = format(tmp, "%Y-%m"), 
    count = as.integer(difftime(pmin(end, i.end), tmp, units = "days")) + 1L)
  }][
    # reorder conveniently
    order(id, month)]
```

> ```
>    id   month count
> 1:  1 2014-01    27
> 2:  1 2014-02     3
> 3:  1 2014-02    25
> 4:  1 2014-03    31
> 5:  1 2014-04    29
> 6:  2 2014-02    23
> 7:  2 2014-03     7
> ```