# Counts of numbers of date for service use in each month

Tags: r, dataframe, function, lubridate

I'm currently re-arranging a health service data. My data frame includes the start and end dates of service use for each individuals

```
id <- c("A", "A", "B")
start <- c("2018-04-01", "2019-04-02", "2018-09-01")
end <- c("2019-04-01", "2019-04-05", "2018-09-02")
df <- data.frame(id, start, end)

 id        start          end
  A    2018-04-01   2019-04-01
  A    2019-04-02   2019-04-05
  B    2018-09-01   2018-09-02
```

I want to do the following things: (1) calculate the number of dates in each month for each service use; (2) calculate dates of service use for each individual; (3) construct new columns for all possible months; and (4) generate a new data frame. The ultimate goal is to construct the following data frame:

```
 id  2018_Jan 2018_Feb 2018_Mar 2018_Apr 2018_May 2018_Jun ... 2018_Sep ... 2019_Sep
  A     0        0         0        30       31       31   ...     30   ...     1
  B     0        0         0         0        0        0   ...      1   ...     0
```

The `lubridate` package and `function` command should be helpful in this. My question is similar to this post [Count the number of days in each month of a date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50933124/count-the-number-of-days-in-each-month-of-a-date-range), where it counted the number of days in each month. However, I'm not sure how to apply it to formulate the data frame that I want.

I will be really grateful for your help on this.

Comment: Do you need the columns with no days (eg, Jan - Mar 2018) in the output?

Comment: Yes, I will need zeros in those months.

Comment: great, I've added this to my answer. also, from your example output, it looks like you *don't* want the `end` date included in the count -- e.g., id `B` runs 9/1 to 9/2/18, which counts as 1 day in the output. Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a {tidyverse} solution.

1. Use `dplyr::summarize()` and `seq()` to generate the full range of dates for each observation.

   - I include `end - 1` in `seq()` to *not* include the end date in the count, consistent with your example.
2. Convert these to months using `lubridate::floor_date(unit = "month")` (technically, changes each date to the first of the month).
3. `dplyr::count()` up month-days for each `id`.
4. Because you want columns for months with no observations in your output, I wrote a function to add unobserved months based on `tidyr::complete()`.
5. Finally, `tidyr::pivot_wider()` to get a column for each month.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

complete_months <- function(.data, month, ..., fill = list()) {
  month <- pull(.data, {{ month }})
  firstday <- floor_date(min(month, na.rm = TRUE), unit = "year")
  lastday <- ceiling_date(max(month, na.rm = TRUE), unit = "year") - 1
  allmonths <- seq(firstday, lastday, by = "month")
  complete(.data, month = allmonths, ..., fill = fill)
}

month_counts <- df %>%
  mutate(across(start:end, ymd)) %>%
  group_by(id, obs = row_number()) %>%
  summarize(
    # use end - 1 in seq() to omit end date from count
    month = floor_date(seq(start, end - 1, by = 1), unit = "month"),
    .groups = "drop"
  ) %>% 
  count(month, id) %>% 
  complete_months(month, id, fill = list(n = 0)) %>% 
  mutate(month = strftime(month, "%Y_%b")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = month,
    values_from = n
  )

month_counts

# # A tibble: 2 x 25
#   id    `2018_Jan` `2018_Feb` `2018_Mar` `2018_Apr` `2018_May` `2018_Jun`
#   <chr>      <int>      <int>      <int>      <int>      <int>      <int>
# 1 A              0          0          0         30         31         30
# 2 B              0          0          0          0          0          0
# # ... with 18 more variables: `2018_Jul` <int>, `2018_Aug` <int>,
# #   `2018_Sep` <int>, `2018_Oct` <int>, `2018_Nov` <int>, `2018_Dec` <int>,
# #   `2019_Jan` <int>, `2019_Feb` <int>, `2019_Mar` <int>, `2019_Apr` <int>,
# #   `2019_May` <int>, `2019_Jun` <int>, `2019_Jul` <int>, `2019_Aug` <int>,
# #   `2019_Sep` <int>, `2019_Oct` <int>, `2019_Nov` <int>, `2019_Dec` <int>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way.  First I make all combinations of id, and year-months from jan 2018 to dec 2019.  Then, I summarize the data by id and year-month.  Finally, join the two datasets together (to make sure you capture the months where nothing happened) and then pivot wider.

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union
id <- c("A", "A", "B")
start <- c("2018/04/01", "2019-04-02", "2018-09-01")
end <- c("2019-04-01", "2019-04-05", "2018-09-02")
df <- data.frame(id, start, end)

all_dates <- expand.grid(id = unique(df$id), 
                         month = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"), 
                         year = 2018:2019) %>% 
  mutate(yrmo = paste(year, month, sep="_")) %>% 
  select(id, yrmo)

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(start = ymd(start), 
         end = ymd(end)) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  summarise(id = id, obs = 1, dates = seq(start, end, by=1)) %>% 
  mutate(yrmo = paste(year(dates), month(dates, label=TRUE, abbr=TRUE), sep="_")) %>% 
  group_by(id, yrmo) %>% 
  summarise(obs = n()) %>% 
  full_join(., all_dates) %>% 
  mutate(yrmo = factor(yrmo, levels = all_dates$yrmo[which(all_dates$id == "A")])) %>% 
  arrange(id, yrmo) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from="yrmo", values_from="obs") %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ifelse(is.na(.x), 0, .x)))
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'id'. You can override using the `.groups`
#> argument.
#> Joining, by = c("id", "yrmo")

df
#> # A tibble: 2 × 24
#> # Groups:   id [2]
#>   id    `2018_Jan` `2018_Feb` `2018_Mar` `2018_Apr` `2018_Jun` `2018_Jul`
#>   <chr>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
#> 1 A              0          0          0         30         30         31
#> 2 B              0          0          0          0          0          0
#> # … with 17 more variables: `2018_Aug` <dbl>, `2018_Sep` <int>,
#> #   `2018_Oct` <dbl>, `2018_Nov` <dbl>, `2018_Dec` <dbl>, `2019_Jan` <dbl>,
#> #   `2019_Feb` <dbl>, `2019_Mar` <dbl>, `2019_Apr` <dbl>, `2019_Jun` <dbl>,
#> #   `2019_Jul` <dbl>, `2019_Aug` <dbl>, `2019_Sep` <dbl>, `2019_Oct` <dbl>,
#> #   `2019_Nov` <dbl>, `2019_Dec` <dbl>, `NA` <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. One line was coded `mutate(yrmo = factor(yrmo, levels = all_dates$yrmo[which(all_dates$id == "A")])`. I wonder if it's restricted to this sample then? I couldn't locate all individuals with multiple records in my actual dataset.

Comment: This is in the matching dataset where all year-months are duplicated for all observations.  Then they are matched up to your observed data.